# how do I find how a view was created?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sqlplus

How do I find out what text was used to create a view in oracle sql, especially how do I find out what columns may be hidden?

```
select view_name, text from all_views where viewname = 'XYZ';
```

will give me the first few words only

sql developer has a tab for this, I'm just wondering if there is a way to do it from the command line in sqlplus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SQL*Plus only shows the first 80 characters of long and clob columns. You can do [`set long 32767`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699121) (or some other large number; 30000 seems to be common, I *think* from older releases where the limit was 32K and that was easier to type, but it is 2M now) and reissue your query.

You can also use [the `dbms_metadata` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885) to get the view DDL, if it is your view (in your schema) or you have the `select catalog` role.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'XYZ')
```

You'll need to do `set long` for that to show you a useful amount of output too; and specify the schema with the third argument if it isn't in your schema.